# Deploy flex app to MAMP server

Tags: apache-flex, macos, adobe, builder, mamp

I created a Flex app in a Windows XP environment using Flex Builder 3.

From the menubar, I selected "Project->Export Build Release" and moved the files from /bin-release onto my local server (WAMP).

I have a PHP file that connects to a db and delivers some data via XML

Everything works right on my computer. Then I tried to move the app to a mac.

I installed MAMP with the default settings (localhost:8888)

I can connect to the PHP file and get the XML by hitting the appropriate URL on @ http://localhost:8888/...

Likewise, I can connect to the html template and the swf executes, but it doesn't seem to be getting the data back, and I don't get any debug info popping up.

Any ideas? Are there security settings enabled by default in Mac OS that would not allow a flex app to request data from a remote resource (i.e. http://localhost:8888/ in this case)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trouble was with the MAMP installation. I reinstalled it, and the app worked.

Answer (score 0):

what is the error that you get?
1. try to catch the FaultEvent
2. do you install any of flash debugger?